# Isn't it time to remove the age from network profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, network-profile, age

Since the [big profile makeover](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244238/profile-page-makeover-part-3-the-prototype-returns/) about two years ago, age is no longer displayed on user profiles.

However, it's still visible in the [network profile](//stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard):

> [image]

I can't see any  point leaving it there when it's removed from all site profiles. Can it please be removed from the network profile as well?

Comment: The DOB input on the profile edit page is also under the headers "Private information *(not shown publicly)*" and "Birthday *(only used for displaying age)*". Probably should do something about that while were at it.

Comment: @Cai well, birth day is never shown publicly indeed, only age so it's correct, and in case it's removed from network profile as well guess we better start a new feature request asking to remove this field when editing the profile. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard We probably wouldn't remove it. It's actually a useful field when it comes to account recovery, for users who forget which email they used. We probably use it more often than the Full Name field.

Comment: @animuson I assume you mean date of birth, not age? What about age in network profile? (And it makes sense, thanks)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, in reference to your comment, not your question. Sorry for the confusion. We wouldn't remove date of birth from the edit profile page.

Comment: @Cai see animuson comment.

Comment: s/bug/big/ in the first line?

Comment: @muru haha, good catch! Too used to submit bug reports... :)

Comment: Speaking as a woman, it's an advantage to me if users can see I am an old hen on my profile page. (Which, sadly, is no longer shown)  In the early days, I had a few pestering comments, and then I posted my age, and voila! Gone! Compliments, never to be seen again. Mission accomplished! ;) Two days ago I received a reminder via a comment that some men can be idiots. I flagged, and the comment was deleted.