# Where did the age go on the network profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page

Ever since the profile redo, the age was shown in the network profile, but not in the per-site profiles. So if someone wanted to see the age, they had to go to the network profile. However.. It's vanished! The field is still there in the profile editing, however. It doesn't appear as if this was implemented: [Isn't it time to remove the age from network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285481/isnt-it-time-to-remove-the-age-from-network-profile)

So... Where is it?

Comment: Hmmm a change to se.com was just pushed out earlier today. Maybe we finally removed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That was an oversight - we removed Age from Profiles ages ago, but still had the code in. When looking at removing the code completely, I saw that SE.com still uses it, and we removed it there as well now.

Comment: So the only way to see age is to go to Area 51 now?

Comment: Age really should not matter, so it's a good thing. @Mithrandir.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yah, but if you're removing it, might as well remove it everywhere.

Comment: @Mithrandir Area 51 is.. different. But feel free to start a new feature request asking to remove it there. :)

Comment: Removed it from Area 51 as well, good catch. It is still in the SE Data Dump because people use those for larger scale data analysis.

Comment: Is this now also removed from the database itself, as result of GDPR? It broke SEDE...

Comment: @ShadowWizard define "broke SEDE"? what exactly are you seeing? but: yes, gone

Comment: @MarcGravell all existing queries that contains the age column now throw error, and there are thousands of those, many linked around in many places. Why not just clear the data and leave it blank?

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are also many queries that filter and group by this. I opted to not silently break these. Since SEDE is also the source of the data dump, we also don't want a forever null column propagating there. There's also having to explain "well...it's there but..." every so often. Given that users are able to fix the queries on their own, I'm okay with this decision.

Comment: @NickCraver thanks, can you please also post it as answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368976/invalid-column-name-age-in-stack-exchange-data-explorer)?

Comment: Also curious about "chain of pings" here... has Michael pinged Marc to come and take a look, then Marc called Nick? :)

Comment: I just happened to see it in our chat. I look through about 34 info feeds for items each Monday morning.